# Project Euler 10 exercise

Tags: c++, long-integer

What is the sum of all the primes below 2000000? 
Example of sum below 10 is 2+3+5+7 = 17

I wrote this code, but still getting the wrong answers:
I tested for numbers lower than a few hundreds, and it has shown the correct answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(long n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return false;
    if (n == 2)
        return true;
    if (n == 3)
        return true;
    int k = 3;
    int z = (int)(sqrt(n) + 1);     // square root the n, because one of the product must be lower than 6, if squared root of 36

    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    while (n % k != 0)
    {
        k += 2;
        if (k >= z)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

long primeSumBelow(long x)
{
    long long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)         // looping for times of prime appearing
    {
        if (isPrime(i) == true)
            total += i;
        if (isPrime(i) == false)
            total += 0;
    }
    cout << "fd" << endl;
    return total;
}

int main()
{
    cout << primeSumBelow(20) << endl;
    cout << primeSumBelow(2000000) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you just forgot a "long" on the return type of the summing function – the sum is more than 60 times greater than what will fit in a signed 32-bit integer, and your local variable has a different type.

Answer (score 0):

The `total` counter's type is correctly `long long`. Unfortunately the function `primeSumBelow` returns only `long` so, depending on the platform, the correctly calculated result is truncated when it's returned from this function.